# How to start a python background process which doesn't block a socket

Tags: python, sockets, subprocess

I've got a Python program which accepts a connection on a socket, reads a command, and then under certain circumstances starts a background sub-process before closing the socket.

The problem is, I can't seem to get the socket to actually close while the sub-process is running.

```
conn, addr = socket.accept()
...
p = Popen([cmd,user], stdin=PIPE)
print "debug1"                         
# the following call doesn't even return until sub-process is exited
#p.communicate(input=text)[0]  
p.stdin.write(text)
print "debug2"
conn.close()
```

I see "debug2" printed immediately, but at the client side the connection does not close until the sub-process terminates.  This is a problem if the sub-process takes a while to complete, as the connection should terminate immediately.

Update: I was just reading that "the key to run a background process is not create an action that depends of the result of the process."  I don't depend on the result of the process, but I do need to send to its stdin.   But if I remove the call to `p.stdin.write` the socket is still blocked.  However, if I don't assign the return value of `Popen` to anything, it *doesn't* block.  But if I don't assign the return value, I can't write to stdin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs:

```
close() releases the resource associated with a connection but does not necessarily
close the connection immediately. If you want to close the connection in a timely
fashion, call shutdown() before close().
```

Comment: that works... I guess my other updated observation was a false lead.  thanks!

Comment: For the record, what's happening is that the child process has inherited a copy of the socket's file descriptor.  Without a call to shutdown(), the socket won't actually be closed until all of the file descriptors pointing  to the socket are close()'d.  Since in this case the child process is some unrelated program being run via popen(), the child process will almost certainly not call close() on that inherited file descriptor (since it doesn't know it exists), so the inherited file descriptor (and therefore the TCP connection) remains open until the child process exits and is cleaned up.